# Multiple conditional formats on a single Object in VBA

Tags: vba, object, if-statement, conditional-formatting

I have an object (i.e. a ractangle shape holding text), i would like to have the shape change colour(status) dependant on the text within a cel(from a drop down list).

I am using 'If' functions to format the shape at present, and i feel this is the best way; however i am not sure how to have multiple 'IF' formulae running in VBA.

i have run a successful 'If' formula for formatting, but this was only able to change between 2 colours. Here is my single 'if' Formula.

```
If Range("I2") = "Deviation" Then
    Worksheets("M2").Shapes("Rect1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(79, 79, 79)
Else
    Worksheets("M2").Shapes("Rect1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 102, 204)
End If
```

When i added other conditions/ 'If' formulae to the script it failed to change the object colour. The closest I got was with 'If' and 'end If' formulae to cover all posibilities. Here is my closest extraction (from my experience).

```
If Range("I2") = "Yes" Then
    Worksheets("M2").Shapes("Rect1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 128, 0)
End If

If Range("I2") = "No" Then
    Worksheets("M2").Shapes("Rect1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(218, 9, 4)
End If

If Range("I2") = "In Progress" Then
    Worksheets("M2").Shapes("Rect1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(201, 129, 13)
End If

If Range("I2") = "Deviation" Then
    Worksheets("M2").Shapes("Rect1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(79, 79, 79)
Else  
    Worksheets("M2").Shapes("Rect1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 102, 204)
End If
```

Comment: Can you try to [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11666218/edit) and indent your code properly, then select it and press the `{}` button to make it look nice?

Comment: You need to use the statement "ElseIf". In this case I would probably go with a Select Case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to Alexandre's answer (don't forget to accept it!), you can refactor a little to avoid repetition:

```
Dim clr As Long

Select Case Range("I2").Value
    Case "Yes": clr = RGB(0, 128, 0)
    Case "No": clr = RGB(218, 9, 4)
    Case "In Progress": clr = RGB(201, 129, 13)
    Case "Deviation": clr = RGB(79, 79, 79)
    Case Else: clr = RGB(0, 102, 204)
End Select

ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rect1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = clr
```

Comment: This is almost perfect, however the object colour only updates when i assign the macro to a button of sorts. I beleiev this is something i need to figure out, maybe a setting is a fault!

Anyhow, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

ElseIf would be an improvement, but the cleanest way is to just use select like this:

```
Select Case Range("I2").Value
    Case "Yes"
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rect1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 128, 0)
    Case "No"
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rect1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(218, 9, 4)
    Case "In Progress"
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rect1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(201, 129, 13)
    Case "Deviation"
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rect1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(79, 79, 79)
    Case Else
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rect1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 102, 204)
End Select
```

This code has been tested to work on my computer.

Edit: Just for the sake of completeness, here is the same code using if/elseif/else:

```
If Range("I2") = "Yes" Then
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rect1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 128, 0)
ElseIf Range("I2") = "No" Then
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rect1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(218, 9, 4)
ElseIf Range("I2") = "In Progress" Then
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rect1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(201, 129, 13)
ElseIf Range("I2") = "Deviation" Then
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rect1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(79, 79, 79)
Else
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rect1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 102, 204)
End If
```

Comment: Hey, thanks... It looks liek it will work, i just went with another answer as i foudn it first.. THANKS!!!